# Cannot Install ResearchKit through CocoaPods (ResearchKit Already Present)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, researchkit

I'm trying to install ResearchKit to support an iOS application project that I am working on, but I'm having trouble installing it using CocoaPods. Despite my best attempt(s) at installing, my project fails on the `import ResearchKit` line in one of the files with an error indicating that ResearchKit cannot be found.

Basic System Information:

- MacOS 10.14.6
- Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)
- CocoaPods 1.9.3

To install CocoaPods, I'm running the `$ pod install` command at the command line. ResearchKit is referenced in my Podfile as follows:

```
pod 'ResearchKit', '2.0.0'
```

And running `$ pod install` yields the following:

```
Installing ResearchKit (2.0.0)

[!] Error installing ResearchKit
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit.git /var/folders/zg/v1h_8jdj5p77k3b208xfl_540000gn/T/d20201019-18654-1lebm6x --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.0.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/zg/v1h_8jdj5p77k3b208xfl_540000gn/T/d20201019-18654-1lebm6x'...
Note: checking out 'b46a5f4d8350549918c8aae7d16b67dcb73fbff9'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

git-lfs filter-process: git-lfs: command not found
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'



[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.1` on target `Master-Sample` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

I am, however, convinced that ResearchKit exists on my system, because running `$ pod search ResearchKit` yields:

```
-> ResearchKit (2.0.0)
   ResearchKit is an open source software framework that makes it easy to create
   apps for medical research or for other research projects.
   pod 'ResearchKit', '~> 2.0.0'
   - Homepage: https://www.github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit
   - Source:   https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit.git
   - Versions: 2.0.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.0, 1.4.1, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.1, 1.2, 1.1.2,
   1.0.0 [trunk repo]
```

Any advice on why the ResearchKit install my be failing during execution of the `$ pod install` command, and/or why, if it is installed on my system, my project is unable to find it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - I needed to install git-lfs. (https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/1219).